# ROW_NUMBER() with DISTINCT

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I've got a table of ticket assignments showing the different groups a ticket is transferred to before its resolved. Here is a simplified table:

```
asgn_grp | date   | ticket_id
---------|--------|----------
       A | 1-1-15 | 1
       A | 1-2-15 | 1
       B | 1-3-15 | 1
       A | 1-1-15 | 2
       C | 1-2-15 | 2
       B | 1-3-15 | 2
       C | 1-1-15 | 3
       B | 1-2-15 | 3
```

I need to get a count of the second distinct group that a ticket was assigned to, meaning I want to know once a ticket is transferred out of the group its in, internal transfers don't count. So the second distinct group for `ticket 1` is `B`, `ticket 2` is `C`, `ticket 3` is `B`. I need to get a count of these, so the end result I need is

```
asgn_grp | count
---------|-------
       B | 2
       C | 1
```

I've tried

```
SELECT distinct top 2 asgn_grp, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date)
```

As my sub-query and pulling the second one out of that, but when I add the `ROW_NUMBER()` it messes up my distinct. If I pull the `ROW_NUMBER()` out of the sub-query, I have now way to order my values to ensure I get the second one after I `DISTINCT` the list.

Also, let me know if I was unclear about anything.

Comment: add `partition by ticket_id` in the OVER clause.

Comment: Also, its probably fair to ask, is this the best way to do this. This is just me guessing... I really wish SQL Server had `limit` and `offset`.

Comment: Don't confuse your familiarity with functional power - the two are distinct.

Comment: Link here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

Comment: FWIW, I don't know what version of SQL Server you're using, but in 2012+ it essentially DOES have limit/offset.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using distinct, try using `group by` twice.

```
select asgn_grp, count(*) from (
    select * , row_number() over (partition by ticket_id order by min_date) rn
    from (
        select asgn_grp, ticket_id, min(date) min_date
        from Table1 group by asgn_grp, ticket_id
    ) t1 
) t2 where rn = 2
group by asgn_grp;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a0d1e

The derived table `t1` contains every unique `asgn_grp` for each `ticket_id` along with the minimum date of each `asgn_grp`. For the sample data `t1` has the following rows:

```
ASGN_GRP    TICKET_ID   MIN_DATE
A   1   January, 01 2015 00:00:00+0000
B   1   January, 03 2015 00:00:00+0000
A   2   January, 01 2015 00:00:00+0000
B   2   January, 03 2015 00:00:00+0000
C   2   January, 02 2015 00:00:00+0000
B   3   January, 02 2015 00:00:00+0000
C   3   January, 01 2015 00:00:00+0000
```

The outer query then uses `row_number()` to number each `asgn_grp` within a `ticket_id` by its min_date and generates the following for `t2`

```
ASGN_GRP    TICKET_ID   MIN_DATE    RN
A   1   January, 01 2015 00:00:00+0000  1
B   1   January, 03 2015 00:00:00+0000  2
A   2   January, 01 2015 00:00:00+0000  1
C   2   January, 02 2015 00:00:00+0000  2
B   2   January, 03 2015 00:00:00+0000  3
C   3   January, 01 2015 00:00:00+0000  1
B   3   January, 02 2015 00:00:00+0000  2
```

This table is filtered for `RN` = 2 and is grouped by `asgn_grp` to get the count for each `asgn_grp`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to identify groups of constant values of `asgn_grp` for each ticket.  You can do that with a difference of row numbers.

Then, you need the ordering for each group.  For that, use the minimum date in the group.  Finally, you can rank these groups to get the second one, using `dense_rank()` on the date.

```
select asgn_grp, count(*)
from (select ticket_id, asgn_grp,
             dense_rank() over (partition by ticket_id order by grpdate) as seqnum
      from (select s.*, min(date) over (partition by ticket_id, asgn_grp, grp) as grpdate
            from (select s.*,
                         (row_number() over (partition by ticket_id order by date) -
                          row_number() over (partition by ticket_id, asgn_grp order by date)
                         ) as grp
                  from simplified s
                 ) s
           ) s
    ) s
where seqnum = 2
group by asgn_grp;
```

Comment: dense_rank in this case is functioning identically to row_number. imho, row_number is preferable here though since if you had two identical dates, you would get duplicated row identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

If you need all assign groups with count zero for non-changed ones, use outer joins instead of inner joins

```
 WITH TBL AS
 (
 SELECT A.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ticket_id ORDER BY asgn_grp) AS RN
 FROM TABLE AS A
 )

 SELECT A.ASSN_GRP, COUNT(*) AS CNT
 FROM TBL AS A
 INNER JOIN TBL AS B
 ON B.TICKET_ID = A.TICKET_ID
 AND A.RN = B.RN + 1 
 GROUP BY A.ASSGN_GRP
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want to know why using `DISTINCT` with `ROW_NUMBER()` changes your results:

- [You can see this question that is about differentioal between `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10652404/4519059).

And from that:

> The `GROUP BY` query aggregates before it computes. The `DISTINCT` query computes before the aggregate.

So When you use `ROW_NUMBER()` -that is a scalar value- if query computes first you will have a unique field for `ROW_NUMBER()` results and then your `DISTINCT` will apply over it that in your result it will not find any duplicate row!

---

And for your results you can use this query

```
SELECT ticket_id, asgn_grp, 
    (SELECT COUNT([date]) FROM yourTable t WHERE t.asgn_grp = r.asgn_grp And t.ticket_id = r.ticket_id)
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ticket_id ORDER BY [date]) As ra
    FROM (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ticket_id, asgn_grp ORDER BY [date] Desc) As rn 
        FROM yourTable) findingOldDates
    WHERE rn = 1) r
WHERE ra = 2
```